# Wavelength and frequency associated with a wave pulse

Tags: waves, fourier-transform, frequency, wavelength, signal-processing

What are the definitions of wave length and frequency of a wave pulse?

Answer (score 0):

There are no definitions, it depends on the length and form of the pulse. You can look it up under Fourier analysis

Comment: That is irrelevant

Comment: Maybe you change your question to something more precise?